# How to limit or control generation of wordpress images sizes for specific image fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm creating a WordPress website programmatically, the thing is i had to create too many images sizes for responsiveness purposes. And that affected the upload time for any image. is there any possible way to limit the images sizes each image upload input generate. I mean if I'm uploading a thumbnail image in the posts. limit the images sizes that would be generated there to just what the post need, and not generating and cropping the image to all the images sizes i created. The same thing goes for ACF fields.

I hope you can understand my question. if you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes! The "too many images generated" is one of my biggest gripes with WordPress. We use a plugin called "[Fly Dynamic Image Resizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fly-dynamic-image-resizer/)" for exactly this purpose.

Comment: thank you Chris for you answer. so this plugin won't create the images sizes while uploading them. but it will create them automatically when visitor visit the images right? and when the visitor visit the page where the image is located it will create just the images sizes i did pass in the function. did i got this right ?

Comment: WordPress will still create any sizes that are registered with `add_image_size`, so you'll want to remove those and watch for plugins that might register some. Core also has some defaults which I'm not sure if all are required or not, but you probably want to keep thumbnail at least. But then you register your new sizes with `fly_add_image_size` and use the fly functions `fly_get_attachment_image_src` and `fly_get_attachment_image` instead of the core functions, and images will only be created when the browser requests the page.

Comment: Additionally, the image dimensions are actually part of the internal naming, so if the `video_thumbnail` size needs to change in the future, just update the size in the definition and new images will be generated when requested, no need to a "regenerate thumbnails" command. All images from Fly are stored in a dedicated folder that doesn't (necessarily) need to be backed up because Fly will auth-generate if they don't exist. If you do change the dimensions on a size a lot, you might want to purge this to clean things up and let Fly regenerate for you.

Comment: alright thank you Chris too much <3